# How to add a character/string after another inside the same format specification

Tags: python

I’m honestly trying to do something pretty simple which is get a formatted string from a list of strings such that the `index+1` is left justified to a specific length but has a period after the index then the string.

Essentially from a list `['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quz']` turn it into a human friendly representation like this:

```
1.   foo
2.   bar
3.   baz
4.   quz
```

Now I’ve done the following:

```
names = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quz']
"\n".join(f"{f'{i}.':<5}{n}" for i, n in enumerate(names, 1)
```

And while this does work, I’m wondering if there’s a better way than nesting that inner f-string as the list of items I’m using is larger than 10 items and just padding a period after the index is not going to work.

Comment: this should be on code review stackexchange, since it's not a programming **problem**.

Comment: But to comment on the question, maybe make a new class that contains your variable, and add a `__str__` magic method that represents your property nicely.

Comment: "*better way*" in terms of what?

Comment: Well the reasoning behind this is because I could just format the index then a period padded by 4 numbers but the lists I’m using get into the double digits so I’d need to pad the index and the period. I added that into the question to add context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
def ndot(n):
    return f'{n}.'

for i in range(8, 12):
    print(f'{ndot(i):<5}XX')
```

prints

```
8.   XX
9.   XX
10.  XX
11.  XX
```

Apply it to your your original answer like so:

```
'\n'.join(f'{ndot(i):<5}{nm}' for i, nm in enumerate(names, 1))
```

Comment: Honestly I should have thought to do that, I just figured there was a way to format it possibly as a float with the decimal point and no trailing zero but there just doesn't seem to be one.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you're using is fine, but some may find it difficult to read. One way that may make it clearer would be to separate the string formatting into its own function, like this:

```py
def format_name(index, name):
    return "{index:<5}{name}".format(index=f"{index}.", name=name)
```

This can be shortened to a one-liner, which I think reads nicely:

```py
>>> format_name = lambda i, name: "{0:<5}{1}".format(f"{i}.", name)
>>> "\n".join(format_name(i, n) for i, n in enumerate(names, 1))
1.   foo
2.   bar
3.   baz
4.   quz
```